# Change OS disk location

Tags: linux, hard-disk, laptop

I have a lenovo laptop with a 1TB HDD disk, I've installed another 240GB SDD drive, I want to translate my currently installed OS (POP_OS) from the HDD to the SDD to keep the OS on the fastest drive for a faster boot and let files, media and other programs in the HDD, is that even possible?. Doesn't matter if I have to format the drive but I would rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Here is how I would do it:

1. Back up all your files. Make sure your `/home` directory is seperate from everything else.
2. Install Pop! OS on the SSD, and:
3. When prompted to choose partitions, choose to mount `EFI` and `/` to partions in the SSD and `/home` to the HDD. This will work best if you format the HDD.
4. After the installation, copy your files back from the backup to their proper place and reinstall any software.

It will take a while, but it's possible.

Since you're new, I would recommend that you look at some tutorials online. You should look specifically at how to work with partitions using `parted`/`gparted` and how to install an OS with `/home` on a seperate partition.

To answer your specific questions: yes it is possible to format from the installer, you can`t select the SSD because you need to create a partition on it first, and you can only edit partitions that are not mounted (not in use).

Comment: I am new in the linux world, do you know if is there any way to format the disk from the popos installer?, or is it a process apart?

Comment: I cannot select the SSD, is locked somehow, and cannot edit nor select anything on the HDD , here is the ![proof](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/802338098507153461/974848938337247273/unknown.png)

Comment: I edited with a followup.

Comment: Ok, so I maybe came a bit late, but what I did was install /boot and /swap on the SDD and / on the HDD, about the partitions and format you were right everything was set up from there, what I still do not if I did correctly is that partd/gparted thing you mention